# Fortigate 10 GE uplink

Tags: routing, ethernet, fortigate

Can i change the speed of the uplink ports on fortigate 600D from 10Ge to GE?
i have core switch alcatel with GE ports need to be integrated with FW 600D

Comment: All the GbE ports already used up?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [transceiver compatibility guide](https://www.fortinet.com/content/dam/fortinet/assets/data-sheets/Fortinet_Transceivers.pdf), SFP transceivers should work in an SFP+ slot.

Comment: +1 All SFP's are compatible with the newer SFP+ standard.

Comment: ... but not all SFP+ slots are compatible with SFP transceivers... ;-)